# Upsert to Phoenix table in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-phoenix

Looking to find if anybody got through a way to perform upserts (append / update / partial inserts/update) on Phoenix using Apache Spark. I could see as per [Phoenix documentation](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html) save `SaveMode.Overwrite` is only supported - which is overwrite with full load. I tried changing the mode it throws error.

Currently, we have *.hql jobs running to perform this operation, now we want to rewrite them in Spark Scala. Thanks for sharing your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Phoenix connector indeed supports only `SaveMode.Overwrite`, the implementation doesn't conform to the Spark standard, [which states that](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes):

> Overwrite mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be overwritten by the contents of the DataFrame

If you check [the source](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/583cdd3e27b80f16ac758f2b0d53d8814a19bdc2/phoenix-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/phoenix/spark/DataFrameFunctions.scala#L59-L69), you'll see that `saveToPhoenix` just calls `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` with `PhoenixOutputFormat`, [which](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_mr.html)

> internally builds the UPSERT query for you

In other words `SaveMode.Overwrite` with Phoenix Connector is in fact `UPSERT`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're right! I also verified it by inserting the same records again.